# Wake On LAN issues

Tags: networking, 18.04, power-management, wakeup

I have an old Toshiba laptop connected to the router via an Ethernet cable. I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 in dual-boot with Windows 10 on it and I am trying to set up Wake On Lan (WOL).

My steps:

1. Enable WOL in BIOS
2. Run `sudo ethtool -s enp1s0 wol g`. Check that the letter has changed from `d` to `g` with `sudo ethtool -s enp1s0`
3. Put the laptop in sleep mode: `sudo systemctl suspend`
4. Install `wakeonlan`. Run `wakeonlan <MAC Address>` from another laptop on the same network.

My other laptop sends the magic packet, but does not wake up the Toshiba laptop.
I have also tried 2 Android apps: [Wake On Lan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.mrwebb.wakeonlan) and [WolOn - Wake on LAN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitklog.wolon). Still, the laptop does not wake up.
What could be the reason?

If I manually wake up the Toshiba by opening the lid and check:

```bsh
sudo ethtool -s enp1s0
```

the letter is back to `d`:

```
...
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
...
```

What does `pumbg` mean?

**Edit**:
`pumbg` seems to indicate the supported WOL modes. They can be seen with `man ethtool`:

```
wol p|u|m|b|a|g|s|d...
                  Sets Wake-on-LAN options.  Not  all  devices  support  this.
                  The argument to this option is a string of characters speci‐
                  fying which options to enable.

                  p   Wake on PHY activity
                  u   Wake on unicast messages
                  m   Wake on multicast messages
                  b   Wake on broadcast messages
                  a   Wake on ARP
                  g   Wake on MagicPacket™
                  s   Enable SecureOn™ password for MagicPacket™
                  d   Disable (wake on  nothing).   This  option
                      clears all previous options.
```

I am able to WOL the laptop in Windows.

---

Regarding Wake On Wireless LAN, when I run:

```bsh
sudo ethtool wlp2s0
```

I get:

```bsh
Settings for wlp2s0:
    Link detected: yes
```

Do I understand it right from this output that my WiFi card does not support WOL?

Answer (score 2):

Your output of `sudo ethtool wlp2s0` does not say if WOL is supported on not, if you want to check that your WNIC(Wireless Network Interface Card) is supported follow the steps from [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-wireless-wake-on-lan-for-linux-wifi-wowlan-card/?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=pmd_439c9374321319eb3257cbbdef65bed1287dc5d7-1626887344-0-gqNtZGzNAzijcnBszQe6)

If you get something like `command failed: Operation not supported (-95)` after you run `iw phy0 wowlan show` your WNIC is not suported.

If your WNIC comes with a pre built PC (f.e. a laptop) most certainly it does not support this future.

Advice: Try use WOL with the Ethernet adapter(usually those support WOL better than WNICs, even builtin ones) or buy a new WNIC that support this feature.

Also related https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=215563